# How to handle windows "Drive not ready", "No disc" etc alert dialog

Tags: python, windows, winapi, alert, removable-storage

Am trying to avoid windows alert showing 'drive not ready' or 'no disc' when running my application. Here is what i have fsp.py

```
import os, win32api
oer = win32api.SetErrorMode( 1 ) #note that SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 1
def check(drive):
    try:
        with open(drive+'\\fsp.check', 'w') as drive_check:
            drive_check.write('000')
        os.unlink(drive+'\\fsp.check')
        return True
    except Exception, e:
        win32api.SetErrorMode(oer)
        return False
```

And mount.py to tell mounted devices.

```
import os
def Query(letters):
#Get mounted devices
    try:
        for l in letters:
            l = l+':\\'
            if os.path.isdir(l):
                yield l
    except Exception, queryex:
        pass
        #print str(queryex)
def main():   
    try:
        return Query(('abefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').upper())
    except Exception, mainex:
        pass
        #print str(mainex)        
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Here is how am trying to use both modules. example.py

```
import mount, fsp
for a in mount.main():
    if fsp.check(a) == True:
        print 'Monted and Ready ', a
    else:
        print 'Mounted but not ready ',a
```

but i still get windows alert. HOW TO AVOID IT. at least by using fsp.py code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a disk is in a drive using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851010/how-do-i-check-if-a-disk-is-in-a-drive-using-python)

Comment: i have already c that but it didn't help.

Comment: `win32api.SetErrorMode(oer)` This will reset the error mode to the pre-`SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` setting the first time an exception is caught.

Comment: i was able to solve the problem. Exception occured when i was trying to mount external devices and therefore i should caught that exception from here         `oer = win32api.SetErrorMode( 1 ) #note that SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS = 1
try:
 for l in letters:
            l = l+':\\'
            if os.path.isdir(l):
                yield l
    except Exception, queryex:
 win32api.SetErrorMode(oer)`